# Give PHP value into Javascript in same page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I give the ID value to Javascript in same page.

Example data :

```
<a href="" id="ctextarea<?php echo $uid; ?>"/>
```

JS :

```
function recountss()
        {
            var maxlen=280;
            var current = maxlen-$('#ctextarea').val().length;
            $('.counters').html(current);


            if(current<0 || current==maxlen)
            {
                $('.counters').css('color','#D40D12');
                $('input.comment_button').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('inact');
            }
            else if (!$.trim($("#ctextarea").val())) {
                $('input.comment_button').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('inact');
            }
            else
                $('input.comment_button').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('inact');


            if(current<10)
                $('.counters').css('color','#D40D12');

            else if(current<20)
                $('.counters').css('color','#5C0002');

            else
                $('.counters').css('color','#C0C0C0');
        }
```

I tried using get class, but it's effect for 1 data not for many data.
Have idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = "ctextarea<?php echo $uid; ?>";
</script>
```

In your javascript, you can do :

```
var current = maxlen-$(id).val().length;
```

But you should use an other name for your variable.

Comment: So how can I set that in my JS ?

Comment: @nagini that does set it in JS. Notice the `script` tags

Comment: Still confused how can set that ? :(

Comment: When you are in a `script` tag, you are writing javascript. So i just use php to generate a javascript value and i store it in the `id` variable. Then in your javascript code, you can use the `id` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try `data-` attributes:

```
<a href="somewhere.php" data-id="<?php echo $uid; ?>" id="link">Link</a>
```

In JS you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById('link').getAttribute('data-id');
```

This stuff is perfectly valid in HTML5 - but even older browsers just don't care.

Comment: I was about to write a similar answer, but I think that the anchor tag is just a dummy element to store a variable.